# Eclipse RCP application - plug-ins organization

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm reading the book `Eclipse Rich Client Platform` by Lars Vogel and in the meantime I'm building an application (not the example on the book).
I must state I'm still half way through the book.

In the example application Lars built, which is a To-do list, he creates a plug-in to hold the Application model (the UI and the main application logic), a plug-in to hold the model (a `Todo` JavaBean) and the service interface, and a plug-in for the service implementation.

Now this works fine if a single entity (`Todo`) is needed, but what if I need multiple entities?
Say for example a `Book, Author, Genre, Publisher` etc. Do I create two plug-ins per entity? Seems to overcomplicate everything.

How should I organize my plug-ins? Should I only separate between Models and Services implementations?

Comment: This is pretty much entirely up to you. But don't worry about having lots of plugins, my fairly simple music player RCP has 55 plugins (not counting the  Eclipse plugins).

Comment: What I'm worried about is the global size of the application, 
 more plug-ins mean more time spent searching classes. Do you have a particular way to organize your apps?

Comment: You will end up with a lot of plugins regardless as Eclipse itself will add something like 90 plugins. Lots of plugins doesn't mean lots of time searching for classes due to the way OSGi plugin classpaths work